# PyTorch RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed

Tags: torch, pytorch

I’m trying to create a basic binary classifier in Pytorch that classifies whether my player plays on the right or the left side in the game Pong. The input is an 1x42x42 image and the label is my player's side (right = 1 or left = 2). The code:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

net = Net(42 * 42, 100, 2)

# Loss and Optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer_net = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), 0.001)
net.train()

while True:
    state = get_game_img()
    state = torch.from_numpy(state)

    # right = 1, left = 2
    current_side = get_player_side()
    target = torch.LongTensor(current_side)
    x = Variable(state.view(-1, 42 * 42))
    y = Variable(target)
    optimizer_net.zero_grad()
    y_pred = net(x)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

The error I get:

```
  File "train.py", line 109, in train
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
  File "/home/shani/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 206, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shani/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 321, in forward
    self.weight, self.size_average)
  File "/home/shani/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 533, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input), target, weight, size_average)
  File "/home/shani/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 501, in nll_loss
    return f(input, target)
  File "/home/shani/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/_functions/thnn/auto.py", line 41, in forward
    output, *self.additional_args)
RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at /py/conda-bld/pytorch_1493676237139/work/torch/lib/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:57
```

Answer (score 11):

For most of deeplearning library, target(or label) should start from 0.

It means that your target should be in the range of  [0,n)  with n-classes.

Comment: that's it! nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like PyTorch expect to get zero-based labels (0/1 in your case) and you probably feed it with one-based labels (1/2)

Comment: Yes, I know but when I tried it, it didn't work. Anyways, I found the problem and changed it back. Now for some reason the model returns values < 0.5 even if the label is always 1.

Comment: Solved the problem :)

Comment: Shani, How did you solved finally. I checked already the labels an are 0 based and also make sure that the output of the network matches with the dimension of my labels, but still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in my program and i just realized that the problem was in the number of output nodes in my neural  network

In my program the number of output nodes of my model was not equal to the number of labels  in dataset

the number of output was 1 and the number of target labels was 10. then i changed the number of output to 10, there was no error