# PyTorch - RuntimeError: Assertion 'cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pytorch

I'm trying to make a neural network with PyTorch to predict student's final exam grades. I've done it like this -

```
# Hyper Parameters
input_size = 2
hidden_size = 50
num_classes =21
num_epochs = 500
batch_size = 5
learning_rate = 0.1

# define a customise torch dataset
class DataFrameDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
def __init__(self, df):
    self.data_tensor = torch.Tensor(df.as_matrix())

# a function to get items by index
def __getitem__(self, index):
    obj = self.data_tensor[index]
    input = self.data_tensor[index][0:-1]
    target = self.data_tensor[index][-1] - 1
    return input, target

# a function to count samples
def __len__(self):
    n, _ = self.data_tensor.shape
    return n

# load all data
data_i = pd.read_csv('dataset/student-mat.csv', header=None,delimiter=";")
data = data_i.iloc[:,30:33]

# normalise input data
for column in data:
# the last column is target
if column != data.shape[1] - 1:
    data[column] = data.loc[:, [column]].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())

# randomly split data into training set (80%) and testing set (20%)
msk = np.random.rand(len(data)) < 0.8
train_data = data[msk]
test_data = data[~msk]

# define train dataset and a data loader
train_dataset = DataFrameDataset(df=train_data)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Neural Network
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.fc1(x)
    out = self.sigmoid(out)
    out = self.fc2(out)
    return out


net = Net(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)

# Loss and Optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Rprop(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# store all losses for visualisation
all_losses = []

# train the model by batch
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for step, (batch_x, batch_y) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # convert torch tensor to Variable
        X = Variable(batch_x)
        Y = Variable(batch_y.long())

        # Forward + Backward + Optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # zero the gradient buffer
        outputs = net(X)
        loss = criterion(outputs, Y)
        all_losses.append(loss.data[0])
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch % 50 == 0:
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            # calculate and print accuracy
            total = predicted.size(0)
            correct = predicted.data.numpy() == Y.data.numpy()

            print('Epoch [%d/%d], Step [%d/%d], Loss: %.4f, Accuracy: %.2f %%'
                  % (epoch + 1, num_epochs, step + 1,
                      len(train_data) // batch_size + 1,
                      loss.data[0], 100 * sum(correct)/total))
```

I'm getting an error at line `loss = criterion(outputs, Y)` which says - 
`RuntimeError: Assertion 'cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at /pytorch/torch/lib/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:62`

I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong as I'm pretty new to this and I've already checked the other posts here but, they don't seem to help.
The `data` dataframe looks like -

```
     30  31  32

0     5   6   6
1     5   5   6
2     7   8  10
3    15  14  15
4     6  10  10
5    15  15  15
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I correct it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch RuntimeError: Assertion \`cur\_target >= 0 && cur\_target < n\_classes' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769206/pytorch-runtimeerror-assertion-cur-target-0-cur-target-n-classes-fail)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in my program 
and i just realized that the problem was in the number of output nodes in my network
In my program the number of output nodes of my model was not equal to the number of labels of the data
the number of output was 1 and the number of target labels was 10. then i changed the number of output to 10, there was no error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is correct, this problem occurs when the class labels are not within the range 0 to MAX (20 in your case).

Comment: I figured that out reading the comments on other discussions. But, I can't seem to fix it. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Just create a map of each real output to one of the classes from 0 to 20. You can do that inside the dataloader.