Huggingface Trainer Finetuning While Using Multi-GPUs Get CUDA Loss Warnings and End up with CUDA Error. [../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250]
I'm following from this script and try to adapt by setting device_map = "auto" for using multiple GPUs in Docker container. Below is the server setting:
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Apr 11 11:39:36 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.08              Driver Version: 545.23.08    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090        On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P8              33W / 350W |     12MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090        On  | 00000000:2B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8              34W / 350W |     12MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090        On  | 00000000:41:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P8              30W / 350W |    155MiB / 24576MiB |      3%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090        On  | 00000000:61:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   32C    P8              32W / 350W |     12MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

Some Python packages version shows below:
Package                   Version
------------------------- --------------
accelerate                0.29.2
bitsandbytes              0.43.0
deepspeed                 0.14.0
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12        10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.19.3
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.4.127
nvidia-nvtx-cu12          12.1.105
peft                      0.10.0
safetensors               0.4.2
tokenizers                0.15.2
torch                     2.2.2
transformers              4.39.3
trl                       0.8.1

All GPUs are running well while only using 1 GPU by the command:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python3 train.py
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python3 train.py
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python3 train.py
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 python3 train.py

However, when calling all GPUs by the command:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 python3 train.py

I got the CUDA Loss warnings and end up with CUDA error.
warnings.warn(
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [1,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
.
.
.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [30,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

I know the error seems caused by the number of labels is not match to the outputs, referred from this forum, but the totally same script is also running well with using multiple GPUs on the other server with the below setting:
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Apr 11 11:52:58 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090         Off| 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P8               40W / 390W|    251MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090         Off| 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   35C    P8               44W / 390W|     10MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

Some Python packages version shows below:
Package                   Version     
------------------------- ------------
accelerate                0.24.1       
bitsandbytes              0.41.1             
deepspeed                 0.11.1     
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.1.3.1    
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.1.105    
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.1.105    
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.1.105    
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         8.9.2.26    
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.0.2.54   
nvidia-curand-cu12        10.3.2.106  
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.4.5.107  
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.1.0.106  
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.18.1      
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.3.52     
nvidia-nvtx-cu12          12.1.105    
peft                      0.5.0      
safetensors               0.4.0
sentencepiece             0.1.99
tokenizers                0.14.1      
torch                     2.1.0     
transformers              4.34.1     
trl                       0.7.11

Also, I've referred to this doc but stuck by the command:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 torchrun --nproc-per-node=4 train.py

I'm not sure if there are some CUDA installing, setting or others difference between both servers that I missed
For UBUNTU, CUDA, Python packages version difference, I tried to install the same environment on the first server but got the same warnings and error.
I also tried to build the environment on host got the same warnings and error, too.

This problem has nothing to do with CUDA. The runtime error is being generated by a an internal bounds check within a GPU kernel being run by PyTorch on the machine you are using. The problem lies in the Pytorch code you are running

https://stackoverflow.com/q/45769206/681865

Hi @talonmies, would you mind sharing skills for test the Pytorch code base on this error? I know the error seems caused by the number of labels is not match to the output, but I've tried run the totally same script with multiple GPUs on another server and it's running well. Thanks a lot!!

But the software versions on the working and non-working versions are completely different -- different Pytorch, different transformers, different accelerate, different bitsandbytes, ..... . Any one of those could be the source of the error. And no, I don't have a 4 GPU system to test on.

In order to check the affect of UBUNTU, CUDA, Python packages version difference, I also tried to install the same environment on the failure server but got the same warnings and error. I also tried to build the environment on host got the same warnings and error, too. I found that I'll get output tensors with large int on the gpu-1,2,3 on failure server (cuda:1, cuda:2, cuda:3) but gpu-0 (cuda:0) is normal. Thanks!!
